# The product of two spectral spaces

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

*Notice: the following statements about the product topologies are all Cartesian product topology, we are in the category of topology not the category of schemes.*

In this page of [sober space](https://planetmath.org/soberspace), it said any product of sober spaces is sober. What does it mean by "any"? Any index or any finite products?

> **Fact 1**. Could anyone give a proof about this fact that the product $X\times Y$ of any two sober spaces $X,Y$ is sober?

I am considering the product topology of two spectral spaces. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec} B$ where $A,B$ commutative rings. Then I wonder to know

> Does there exist a canonical choice of a ring $C$ such that $\operatorname{Spec} C$ is cannonically isomorphic to the Cartesian topology of $X\times Y$?

The topologies of $X,Y$ are quasicompact, and they have bases consisting of quasicompact opens and the intersection of any two quasicompact open is quasicompact open. Those above properties are preserved in $X\times Y$ (if I am right). So by *Fact 1*, the product topology of $X\times Y$ is a [spectral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space), thus it can be realized as a spectrum of a commutative ring (see the same wiki article).

Moreover, if we are considering the product topology $X\times_Z Y$ (the induced topology of the product topology $X\times Y$), where $X,Y,Z$ are affine schemes the maps $X\to Z$, $Y\to Z$ are induced by the ring maps, what will happen in this case, is $X\times_Z Y$ a spectral space, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of Fact 1 (for any product).

Let $\{ X_i \}_{i\in I}$ be a family of non-empty sober spaces. Let $F$ be a closed irreducible subset of $X:=\prod_i X_i$. By replacing $X_i$ with the closure of the projection of $F$ in $X_i$, we can suppose $F\to X_i$ has dense image for all $i$.

I claim that $F=X$. If $\eta_i$ is the generic point of $X_i$, then it is clear that $(\eta_i)_i$ is the generic point of $X$. So let's prove the claim. Suppose the open subset $X\setminus F$ is non-empty. Then it contains a product 
$$X\setminus F \supseteq U_{i_1}\times \cdots \times U_{i_n} \times \prod_{i\ne i_1,..., i_n} X_i$$
with non-empty open subsets $U_{i_j}\subseteq X_{i_j}$. 
So $F$ is covered by finitely many closed subsets of $X$:
$$ F\subseteq \cup_{1\le j\le n} Z_{i_j}\times \prod_{i\ne i_j} X_i$$
where $Z_{i_j}=X_{i_j}\setminus U_{i_j}$. As $F$ is irreducible, it is contained in one of them, say 
$$ F\subseteq Z_{i_1}\times \prod_{i\ne i_1} X_i.$$
But then the projection of $F$ to $X_{i_1}$ is not dense. Contradiction.

Comment: Dear @QiL, Your proof is very very clear! Beautiful writting. Thanks!

Comment: @wxu, thanks. For your second question, I don't think there is a reasonnable answer. For example, if $Y$ is the spectrum of a field $K$, so $X\times Y= X$, then what would be $C$ ? Remember that you can't recover the ring $A$ from $X$.

Comment: I agree with you. Also, even if  $A=B$ are DVRs, the ring $C$ will become a non-Noetherian ring (by krull's principal theorem).