# Non sober spaces, products and Alexandroff topology

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders, topos-theory

According to the Scholium 1.1.4 in Part C of Peter's Johnstone ,,Sketeches of the Elephant'' the free frame $F(A)$ over a set $A$ can be realized as $\mathcal{O}(X)$ for suitable topological space $X$. The space $X$ can be constructed as $KA^{op}$ (the family of finite subsets of $A$ with the inverse order) with the Alexandroff topology (where a set is open iff it is lower set) but also $X$ can be realized as $S^A$ where $S$ is the Sierpiński space. It is known that two topological spaces $X,Y$ are homeomorphic iff the frames $\mathcal{O}(X)$ and $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ are isomorphic provided these two spaces are *sober*. Since the cardinality of $KA$ is less than that of $S^A$ these two spaces clearly are not homeomorphic. Therefore one of them can not be sober. Somewhere I have read that the product of sober spaces is again sober.

> Could someone point me some reference for this result?

If it is so, then $KA^{op}$ cannot be sober:

> However I would also like to see a direct proof of the fact that $KA^{op}$ is not sober.

Comment: Regarding the first question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151016/the-product-of-two-spectral-spaces. As for the second question, I suppose you can ask more generally if there's a poset-theoretic criterion for when a poset with its Alexandrov topology is sober. A first question is then: can you characterise closed irreducible subsets and compare them with closures of points?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Since I came looking for what you hinted at, I will write my conclusions here for posterity: Given a topological space $X$, the function $f_X:x\mapsto\overline{\{x\}}$ is a map from points of $X$ to irreducible closed subsets of $X$. We have that $X$ is T₀ iff $f_X$ is injective, $X$ is quasi-sober iff $f_X$ is surjective and $X$ is sober iff $f_X$ is bijective. That is, a space is sober iff it is T₀ and quasi-sober. Now let $(X,\leq)$ be a preordered set, and view it as a topological space endowed with the specialization topology (a subset $Z$ of $X$ is

Comment: closed if and only if it is upwards-closed, i.e., $x\leq y$ and $x\in Z$ implies $y\in Z$). We know that $X$ is T₀ if and only if $X$ is an ordered set, so to characterize sobriety it suffices to characterize quasi-sobriety. For $x\in X$, one can verify that $\overline{\{x\}}=\{y\in X\mid x\leq y\}$. Thus, $X$ is quasi-sober if and only if every irreducible closed subset has a minimum (for $\leq$). Finally, irreducible closed subsets of $X$ are characterized proset-theoretically to be the upwards-closed subsets of $X$ that cannot be written as a union of two upwards-closed proper subsets.

Comment: If anyone knows a proset-theoretical characterization of irreducibility different from the one above (which is just a direct translation of the topological definition), please, let me know ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $KA^{op}$ is not sober (for $A$ infinite), just observe that $KA^{op}$ is irreducible: any two basic open sets have nonempty intersection, since you can take the union of the corresponding finite subsets of $A$.  But $KA^{op}$ does not have a generic point, since there is no largest finite subset of $A$.